# Function in Javascript Create Element

Tags: javascript, element

Hello I am using create element and my question is if the function can be executed when the page is loaded something like in jquery "document ready".

I am currently using this code which works when the user clicks on the div. It works for me for other purposes but now I need the function to run when the div loads or when the page loads.

My code:

```json
s.a.createElement("div", { id: "iframe", style: { backgroundColor: "red" },
                                        onClick: function () {
                                        document.getElementById("iframe").innerHTML += "<iframe src='https://site.test' frameborder='0' id='iframe' style='display: block; overflow: hidden; border: none; height: 100vh; width: 100vw;'></iframe>";
                                        },
                                        },      
                                        ),
```

Poor changing onClick for OnLoad but without success.

I tried this but it gives me an error.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
});
```

```
s.a.createElement("div", { id: "iframe", style: { backgroundColor: "red" },
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
                                        document.getElementById("iframe").innerHTML += "<iframe src='https://site.test' frameborder='0' id='iframe' style='display: block; overflow: hidden; border: none; height: 100vh; width: 100vw;'></iframe>";
                                        },
                                        },      
                                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('page is fully loaded');
});
```

I think u meant that.

Comment: Generate error create element. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

Comment: check this https://i.imgur.com/s65yShH.png

Answer (score 0):

You are certainly looking for the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
});
```

This fires once the HTML is available, but before images are loaded etc. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: generate error check this please https://i.imgur.com/s65yShH.png

Comment: That picture does not say much... If it's a parse error, could it be that the arrow functions are not working on whatever browser you use?